# Angular 2 - HighCharts implementation: Cannot find name 'HighchartsOptions'

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am currently trying to implement Highcharts in my Angular2 Project. Unluckily I get this Error: Cannot find name 'HighchartsOptions'
The tutorial-link which I used.
www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#installation

[Browser log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQUE.png)
[Module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T685H.png)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'simple-chart-example',
template: `
    <chart [options]="options"></chart>
`
})
export class MyChart {
constructor() {
this.options = {
  title : { text : 'simple chart' },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
  }]
};
}
options: HighchartsOptions; //That's the line where I get the error
enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
options:HighchartsOptions
```

to...

```
options:Object;
```